# Having issues unzipping a .tgz file

Tags: file, terminal, directory, unzip

Trying to open a zipped file with a .tgz extension in the desktop, tried opening with archive utility and am being told 'unable to expand into desktop' error 1 - operation not permitted. When i try to unzip the file in terminal it says it cannot be found.

No idea what's going on. Any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .tgz extension implies that the arhive is a zipped 'tar ball'. So there are two kinds of compression applied to the file. Is it possible that you are using a windows utility that can unzip but not untar? If not, if you are in Linux try using the console and running the command: `tar -zxvf <yourarchive>.tgz`